# jq - how to transform a nested structure into another?

Tags: json, jq

I have a like 950 json files that I need to transform but I'm kinda stuck. I have right a shell script to iterate over files, delete somekeys but I got stuck on how transform it. Here I have my original file:

```
{ 
  "name": "Ted Mosby",
  "addresses": {
    "data": [
      {
        "key": "address key",
        "value": "any xpto"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to transform `data` into another format and output must be:

```
{
  "name": "Ted Mosby",
  "addresses": {
      "data": [{
        "value": "any xpto",
        "remoteRef": {
            "key": "address key",
            "courrierStrategy": "Auto"
        }
      }]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve it using jq? I am trying to avoid write a python to perform it.

Answer (score 2):

You could update `|=` the `.data` array by applying a transformation to each of its elements, using the `.key` and `.value` from the original item:

```
.addresses.data |= map({value, remoteRef: {key, courrierStrategy: "Auto"}})
```

```json
{
  "name": "Ted Mosby",
  "addresses": {
    "data": [
      {
        "value": "any xpto",
        "remoteRef": {
          "key": "address key",
          "courrierStrategy": "Auto"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/QNAI4Ouqk83)